Can I install playwright (ms-playwright folder) into a directory OTHER than under my %USERPROFILE% in Windows?
My work computer has a restriction for running executables and calling DLLs outside of a specific directory.  That specific directory is a "Developer exemption/exception".  I would very much like to build end-to-end tests with Microsoft Playwright, but it installs in two places:

The code folder (ex: C:\targetDirectory\applications\targetApplication\...) and
A bunch of executables and DLLs under my %USERPROFILE% here:


C:\Users\patflyer\AppData\Local\ms-playwright (though I have
noticed these are mostly the browsers)

My question is, can I install (relatively) everything under a target directory like:

C:\targetDirectory\

...and by doing so, avoid offending the IT Security exemption granted to developers to use ONLY the "targetDirectory" folder (and any subfolders underneath it)?
Please assume I want to use all of the specific browsers that come with Playwright (Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, and Webkit).  I'd install without those browsers and point at the ones installed in C:\Program Files\ (if I had to).  Please let me know and thank you.
I tried looking for any reference to USERPROFILE or %USERPROFILE% as that seems to be part of the installation.  I did find a reference to an error message if it was a relative path:

lib\server\firefox\firefox.js:    if
(!_path.default.isAbsolute(os.homedir())) throw new Error(Cannot launch Firefox with relative home directory. Did you set ${os.platform() === 'win32' ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME'} to a relative path?);

